# How to create a list of objects of certain class type in Dart?

Tags: python, dart, types, anonymous-function, anonymous-class

I have this code in Python 3.x:

```
_VectorOf = lambda ownerObj,classType,scope: [classType(ownerObj) for i in scope]
```

This code create a list of "classType" objects."classType" is any class passed by user.

How would it be in Dart 2.7.x? I don't wish to use "dart:mirrors" if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're talking about using a type variable (or generic type label) to instantiate an instance object of that type. This isn't possible in Dart without using `dart:mirrors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
List<T> vectorOf<T>(int length, T createObject()) => 
    [for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) createObject()];
```

If you want to create an object, you have to say how to create it.

The type is not enough. It *might* be enough with `dart:mirrors`, but only if the type actually has a constructor. And it's a class type at all, and not, say, a function type or `FutureOr<void>` or something else which cannot have a constructor at all.

An example could be:

```dart
var listOfStringLists = vectorOf(12, () => <String>[]);
```

This creates a list of length 12 where each element is a new empty list of strings.

If you need to parameterize the factory function with an extra parameter, then you just have to pass it through manually:

```dart
List<T> vectorOf<T, O>(int length, O owner, T createObject(O owner)) => 
    [for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) createObject(owner)];
```

This will pass the `owner` object as a parameter to `factory` every time it's called.
Another option is:

```dart
List<T> vectorOf<T, O>(int length, O owner, T createObject(O owner)) =>
    List<T>.generate(length, (_) => createObject(owner));
```

where you use the `List.generate` constructor, but ignores the index it passes to its factory function.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Dart, and I don't understand how to use "factory", I've googled for help but I find topics about "factory constructors", and they show examples very different to yours, so I'm confused. How do I use this anonymous function (an example please)? In my Python code "ownerObj" is the owner (passed as parameter to constructor) per every object created, but it is not in your code sample, how do I add it? Thanks

Comment: I've tried adding an example. The function here is *factory function*, not a *factory constructor*. It's not a special kind of function, it's just what we call a function which creates an object. It's a "factory" as in the ["factory method" design pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-patterns-set-2-factory-method/). I'm not sure I understand what "ownerObj" does. If you need to pass a parameter to the factory function, then you just have to do that explicitly. I'll add an example of that too.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα The use of `factory` in this case is misleading. It's not using the keyword "factory" to create a special kind of Dart thing, but is instead taking a function parameter for creating an object of type `T` that just happens to be named "factory". It could (and perhaps should) be renamed to remove this confusion.